# C++: copy constructor for iterators

Tags: c++

I am currently in the process of refreshing my knowledge of the language, and have found the following example [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/iterator/) defining an iterator class. Am I mistaken in saying that the way the copy constructor in this iterator is defined in such a way that it will only create a shallow copy or am I missing something?

Wouldn't this create problems when used given that the class attribute is an int pointer?

Thanks.

```
// std::iterator example
#include <iostream>     // std::cout
#include <iterator>     // std::iterator, std::input_iterator_tag

class MyIterator : public std::iterator<std::input_iterator_tag, int>
{
  int* p;
public:
  MyIterator(int* x) :p(x) {}
  MyIterator(const MyIterator& mit) : p(mit.p) {}
  MyIterator& operator++() {++p;return *this;}
  MyIterator operator++(int) {MyIterator tmp(*this); operator++(); return tmp;}
  bool operator==(const MyIterator& rhs) const {return p==rhs.p;}
  bool operator!=(const MyIterator& rhs) const {return p!=rhs.p;}
  int& operator*() {return *p;}
};
```

Comment: FWIW, `std::iterator` is [deprecated](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/iterator) since C++17. It only defines a few typedefs for you which are you are now supposed to do by hand.

Comment: Aside: I'd remove that copy constructor, as `MyIterator` can easily follow the rule of zero

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The concept of "deep" copying only applies to objects owning another object through some kind of reference (e.g. a pointer). The iterator uses its value (the pointer) in an non-owning fashion, and so copying the value of that pointer is enough to maintain the semantics of the class.

In fact (as pointed by Caleth in the comments), in this case the compiler would generate precisely this copy-ctor by default, so you don't even have to write it.

If your copy-ctor actually copied the data being pointed to, it wouldn't be a very good iterator, because you'd then lose the access to the object you wanted to iterate.